# Redirect streams for prompting passwords

Tags: bash, redirect, passwords, stream, prompt

I have a script that prompt for a password to achieve a specific task. I wanna skip entering password each time. for this, i thought about sth like that:

```
./myscript < my_file_containing_pass
```

but unfortunatly, this doesn't work.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have a newline in the end of your password file.

If that didn't work, set an environment variable, and alter your script so that if it finds this env. variable, it reads the password from the file with the variable value, otherwise it prompts the user.

Comment: the script is not mine, i can't edit it. I think it's related of the way passwords are prompted, i tried with this script: "read password < my_file && echo $password" it works just fine.